# Android 11: Persist app data even if app is uninstalled (using Android 11, API 30)

Tags: android

How do I persist app data even if the app is uninstalled (using Android 11, API 30)?

On Android 11 following things don't work:

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

What works is getExternalFilesDir() but when the app is uninstalled, the data created by app also gets deleted.

Is there any solution?

Comment: The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) has a nice table for you. So basically you got 2 options, `MediaStore API` or `Storage Access Framework`

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` Still works.

Comment: Write your files to the public Documents folder.

Comment: Can someone please give the code. Thanks.

Comment: I was using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() earlier, but at run time I got an exception that file or folder does not exist.

Comment: @Ricky: I had read that but I could not figure out how to use "Storage Access Framework". Can you help here? Thanks.

Comment: @blackapps: Can you please give me the code to get public Documents folder path. Thanks.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).

Comment: @blackapps: Thanks. I am able to create my folder in public documents directory. But now there is a new problem: while trying to read my file from my folder in public documents directory, it is giving me "permission denied" even though I have taken permission from user for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: That makes no sense. If your app can create a folder there and create/write a file in it it can surely read the file too.

Comment: My folder had a leading dot. After removing the leading dot, I could read my file in that folder. It is strange that a folder with leading dot can be created but cannot be read.

Comment: That dot story makes no sense either.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is by blackapps: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).

But now there is another problem. May be I will ask another question.

Android 11 is weird. When I delete my file "manually" from Documents folder, my "app" fails to create the file because android thinks that file still exists.

This is the code

```
if (!configFile.exists()) {
  if (configFile.createNewFile() == false) {
    showToast("Failed to create file " + configFile.getAbsolutePath());
  }
}
```

configFile.exists() returns false and createNewFile() also returns false. This is very strange.